# subclassing TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource in TwitterKit / Fabric iOS for geolocation

Tags: ios, twitter, geolocation, twitter-fabric

I would like to make a search query using the geolocalization parameter allowed through the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search):

> - You want: all recent tweets done in Portuguese, near Maracanã soccer stadium in Rio de Janeiro
> - Your search URL is: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent

I am using TwitterKit from Fabric iOS to display a search timeline like so:

```m
TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource *searchTimelineDataSource = 
    [[TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithSearchQuery:searchTerm 
                                                    APIClient:APIClient];
```

https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-timelines.html.

Unfortunately, if you look at the [`TWTRTimelineDataSource.h`](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Protocols/TWTRTimelineDataSource.html) header file, there is a comment that says:

> Not implemented: `geocode`, `result_type`

Even though the Twitter API documentation warns us that the 'near' operator isn't available, I tried the "near:within:" parameters (e.g., `searchTerm = @"Apple near:NYC within:100mi"`), since according to the Fabric [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Classes/TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource.html), `searchTerm` in this case is exactly "the query string that you would type into https://twitter.com/search". As expected, you get back an error:

```
[TwitterKit] Couldn't load tweets from TWTRTimelineViewController:...
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=30&result_type=filtered&q=%23AppleEvent%20near%3ANYC%20within%3A100mi%20-filter%3Aretweets, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : near parameter is invalid. (code 44)}
```

I can't find the actual source code for `TWTRTimelineDataSource.m` anywhere, so I don't think I am able to subclass it in order to add the geocode query capability myself. Is there any other way I could still use the built-in `TWTRTimelineViewController` with a geolocation query?